# Is Craft suitable for large websites?

Tags: craft-features

We're looking at various CMSs for our large 11,000+ page website. We'd like to use a CMS that is appropriate for sites of that size and that will give us room to grow without impacting site speed, page load time, etc. I see other questions on this forum regarding site size, but all use CraftCMS terminology, such as 'channels', 'structures', etc to describe size.
How can CraftCMS size capability be described in pages?

Thank you.

Comment: "Pages" can mean a lot of things... what kind of pages are you describing? Are we talking about 11,000 news articles, or 11,000 user profile pages, or something else entirely? The answer may vary wildly based on exactly what _kind_ of content you're storing.

Comment: In addition to what @lindsey is asking, how complex is your content? Are there a lot of relationships between articles, or are they just generally categorized/tagged? Is there any dynamic content specific to users that cannot be cached, or is everything pretty much static and can be cached for long periods of time?

Comment: Our content is 70% static content, but perhaps we'd want to feed some of the profiles or news articles, etc to some of the pages. We also do have some dynamic content, but most of it is not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, absolutely. Craft have some case studies which illustrate that top brands trust them to handle large amounts of content while making it **easy to publish** more: https://craftcms.com/news/case-studies

My second point is a huge selling point for a good CMS. If your publishing process is difficult or confusing then you as an admin/client become frustrated. Craft is fast and easy to digest from a publishers point of view.

(Wes mentioned relationships)
By design, you should only need to add a piece of content to your CMS once - and then 'relate' different entries together as new ones are published. e.g. A new '**Service**' (entry) is related to an '**office location**' (entry) where that service is provided.  Then, when a visitor is viewing that office location they are able to see any services which may be available there. (Just a simplified example)

Planning and designing what your content-types consist of and how different types of content can work together to tell a story to a visitor - will mitigate any major shifts in direction which often happen on-the-fly (the most expensive way to build a website).

**Coming back to your question.** 
Craft is very good at storing your content efficiently.

Craft uses Twig as a template language, which requests content from Craft. The trick is to only tell Twig to get what you need for any given page. This isn't hard once you understand the approach.

Images are also uploaded **once** and then re-saved ([image transforms)](https://craftcms.com/docs/image-transforms) into different sizes as they are used differently through your site.

The effect is that instead of slowly trying to load an image which is large in size, a small image is loaded quickly.

Hope that helps. I'm sure you'll get more answers too...

Comment: Thank you, this answer is very helpful. I've marked it as the answer.

Comment: Another related question- our site is composed of many subsites which have different users contributing to them. Would it be possible within CraftCMS to restrict a user's login to only viewing the content that they can edit (ie- within their 'subsite' area)? I say viewing since we have a LOT of content and I'd like to keep the content separate for different users to prevent confusion.

Comment: Actually, I'm moving my second question to a new question. Thanks for your help.